# wordpress template_directory in a link - php

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I try to work with the given syntax `template_directory()` for links.

If I use the full path from root directory it works.

```
$ptthlider_img_second = '/wp/wp-content/themes/theme_name/inc/img/front_slider/slide2.jpg';
```

My wished goal is to use `template_directory` for accessing the `jpg`.

```
$ptthlider_img_first = template_directory() . '/inc/img/front_slider/slide1.jpg';
```

Do you have any conclusions to assist me here?

Thanks and best regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `get_template_directory()` [get_template_directory documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/)

Comment: Thanks in Advance! This solved my (seemed little) issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_template_directory() as Daniel mentioned.

Good to know:

1. get_template_directory() will return the path of parent theme.
2. get_stylesheet_directoty() will return the path of child theme if you are using one.
3. They return path without trialing slashes.

In addition there is a function get_bloginfo('template_directory') and get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'), that can also be used for same purposes.